# How to reference all instances of a generic class?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, abstract-class

I've not completely wrapped my head around one aspect of Generics.

Let's say I have a Generic class:

```
public abstract SomeClass<T> where T : SomeInterface
{
    public bool DoSomethingsWithT(T theItem)
    {
        //doStuff!!!
    }

    public virtual bool IsActive
    {
       get { return true; }  
    }
}
```

So basicly I assume versions that inherit this class to be Active but I allow some of them to define their own.

Now later on I'm getting an object into a method that I know will be of the type `SomeClass<T>` but T could be any class implementing `SomeInterface`

```
public bool SomeMethod(object item)
{
    var something = item as SomeClass;

    return something.IsActive;
}
```

But this of course doesn't work as there is no class named `SomeClass` and I also can't do `SomeClass<SomeInterface>` as even if another class does inherit from this I'm unable to cast this.

How is this normally done? Should we create a class named `SomeClass` that `SomeClass<SomeInterface>` inherits from and in that class we define the `IsActive` property.

I'm seeing this same exact problem If I was gonna create a collection of items that inherit `SomeClass<SomeInterface>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an interface to implement on the generic class:

```
interface ISomeClass
{
    bool IsActive {get;}
}

public abstract SomeClass<T> : ISomeClass where T : SomeInterface
{
    public bool DoSomethingsWithT(T theItem)
    {
        //doStuff!!!
    }

    public virtual bool IsActive
    {
       get { return true; }  
    }
}

public bool SomeMethod(object item)
{
    var something = item as ISomeClass;

    return something.IsActive;
}
```

Comment: So my assumption was right as you and Dan Tao mention. So basically I would let the interface have all class members that are independent of `T` and everything dependent on `T` inside the generic version?

Answer (score 4):

How about deriving from a class/implementing an interface that contains the common behaviour:

```
interface IIsActive
{
    bool IsActive{get;}
}
```

Comment: That would be a great way to solve the problem here, upvote for that. But I was mainly asking generally about referencing Generic classes.

Answer (score 2):

> Should we create a class named `SomeClass` that `SomeClass<SomeInterface>`
>   inherits from and in that class we define the `IsActive` property.

Yep, that's exactly what you should do (and is how this is normally done).

*Or* you could follow [spender's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667621/how-to-reference-all-instances-of-a-generic-class/6667686#6667686) and use an interface instead of an abstract class. This is probably better, as it accomplishes the same goal without restricting you to a rigid type hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Use the interface not the Class implementation

```
public bool SomeMehtod(object item)
{
    return ((SomeInterface)item).IsActive;
}
```

Just realized that the IsActive property and you are defining is not in the interface.

Then the best way to do this is to determine if the class is a `SomeClass` and then return the `IsActive`

```
public bool SomeMethod(object item)
{
    var something = item as SomeClass;
    if (something != null)
    {
        return something.IsActive;
    }
    else
    {
        return somethingElse;
    }
}
```

Comment: that wont work... item is SomeClass<SomeInterface>, not SomeInterface

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I've got this right, but would this method signature work for SomeMethod?

```
    public bool SomeMethod(SomeClass<SomeInterface> item)
    {            
        return item.IsActive;
    }
```

Comment: The second code block will not work: InvalidCastException
"Unable to cast object of type 'ConcreteType' to type 'SomeClass`1[SomeInterface]'."

Comment: @Jacob: Fair enough - wasn't sure without implementing it. Have removed it.

Comment: Well the SomeMethod could be a overridden method of some abstract class where I have no control over the profile. Could be a SortingMethod for example but I would know that the collection being sorted is of SomeClass type.